# How do I remove the UINavigationBar from a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm experimenting with the NavBar sample project for iPhone.  When I tap on one of the rows in the table in the default view a new view slides in (so far so good).  I want to remove the UINavigationBar bar at the top of the new view that slides in.  How can I do this?

EDIT:  I meant "UINavigationBar".  Thanks to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you referring to the status bar (where the time and battery status are shown) or the UINavigationBar (where the title and Back buttons are)?

- To hide the status bar, use  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;`  in your `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.
- To hide the UINavigationBar, you'll want to use the `navigationBarHidden` property of your UINavigationController.

Comment: Pardon my noobery, but where and how does one get to and modify the "-applicationDidFinishLaunching:" method?

Comment: This is a method on your Application Delegate. You'll need to read about application delegates for more information than that: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html

Answer (score 2):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setHidesStatusBar:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either hide it programmatically by called setHidesStatusBar on your UIApplication (sharedApplication), or you can set it in the plist. Check the CrashLanding's plist.

Comment: Setting it in the pList is good because if you hide it there it won't show up on your splash screen.